# Can't get rid of Error lnk2001

Tags: c++, variables, static, lnk2001

Hey guys and gals I need some serious assistance. I have this final and its due in 2 days and some hours. However I am unable to resolve this lnk2001 error at the end of my program. Please help me I have no clue how to resolve. I left the instructors desires in the coding as comments.

```
    #include <iostream>
#include <string> 
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;
using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;


//
//CLASS DECLARATION SECTION
//
class EmployeeClass {
public:
void ImplementCalculations(string EmployeeName, double hours, double wage);
void DisplayEmployInformation(void);
static double Addsomethingup(EmployeeClass, EmployeeClass, EmployeeClass);
string EmployeeName;
double hours;
double wage;
double basepay;
double overtime_hours;
double overtime_pay;
double overtime_extra;
static double iTotal_salaries;
static double iIndividualSalary;
static double iTotal_hours;
static double iTotal_OvertimeHours;
};

int main()
{
system("cls");

cout << "Welcome to the Employee Pay Center" << endl;

/*
These are my three employees
*/
EmployeeClass Employ1;
EmployeeClass Employ2;
EmployeeClass Employ3;


/*
Here you will prompt for the first employee’s information.
Prompt the employee name, hours worked, and the hourly wage.  For each piece                    
of information, you will update the appropriate class member defined above.
Example of Prompts
Enter the employee name      =
Enter the hours worked       =
Enter his or her hourly wage =
*/
cout << "Enter the employee name." << endl;
cin >> Employ1.EmployeeName;
cout << "Enter the hours worked." << endl;
cin >> Employ1.hours;
cout << "Enter his or her hourly wage." << endl;
cin >> Employ1.wage;


/*
Here you will prompt for the second employee’s information.
Prompt the employee name, hours worked, and the hourly wage.  For each piece 
of information, you will update the appropriate class member defined above.
Enter the employee name      =
Enter the hours worked       =
Enter his or her hourly wage =

*/
cout << "Enter the employee name." << endl;
cin >> Employ2.EmployeeName;
cout << "Enter the hours worked." << endl;
cin >> Employ2.hours;
cout << "Enter his or her hourly wage." << endl;
cin >> Employ2.wage;

/*
Here you will prompt for the third employee’s information.
Prompt the employee name, hours worked, and the hourly wage.  For each piece 
of information, you will update the appropriate class member defined above.
Enter the employee name      =
Enter the hours worked       =
Enter his or her hourly wage =

*/
cout << "Enter the employee name." << endl;
cin >> Employ3.EmployeeName;
cout << "Enter the hours worked." << endl;
cin >> Employ3.hours;
cout << "Enter his or her hourly wage." << endl;
cin >> Employ3.wage;


/*
Here you will implement a function call to implement the employ calcuations 
for each object defined above.  You will do this for each of the three 
employees or objects.
The format for this step is the following:
[(object name.function name(objectname.name, objectname.hours, 
objectname.wage)] ;
*/
Employ1.ImplementCalculations(Employ1.EmployeeName, Employ1.hours, 
Employ1.wage);
Employ2.ImplementCalculations(Employ2.EmployeeName, Employ2.hours, 
Employ2.wage);
Employ3.ImplementCalculations(Employ3.EmployeeName, Employ3.hours, 
Employ3.wage);
EmployeeClass::Addsomethingup(Employ1, Employ2, Employ3);

}
/*
This section you will send all three objects to a function that will add up 
the the following information:
- Total Employee Salaries
- Total Employee Hours
- Total Overtime Hours

The format for this function is the following:
-   Define a new object.
-   Implement function call [objectname.functionname(object name 1, object 
name 2, object name 3)]
/*

} //End of Main Function*/


void EmployeeClass::ImplementCalculations (string EmployeeName, double 
hours, double wage){
//Initialize overtime variables
    basepay = wage;
overtime_hours=0.0;
overtime_pay=0.0;
overtime_extra=0.0;

if (hours > 40)
{
    EmployeeClass::hours = 40.0;
    EmployeeClass::overtime_hours = hours - 40;
    EmployeeClass::overtime_pay = wage * 1.5;
    EmployeeClass::overtime_extra = overtime_hours * overtime_pay;
    EmployeeClass::iIndividualSalary = overtime_extra + (wage * 
EmployeeClass::hours);



    /*
    This section is for the basic calculations for calculating overtime pay.
    -   base pay = 40 hours times the hourly wage
    -   overtime hours = hours worked – 40
    -   overtime pay = hourly wage * 1.5
    -   overtime extra pay over 40 = overtime hours * overtime pay
    -   salary = overtime money over 40 hours + your base pay
    */

    /*
    Implement function call to output the employee information.  Function is 
defined below.
    */

}


 else
{
    EmployeeClass::hours = hours;
    EmployeeClass::overtime_hours = 0.0;
    EmployeeClass::overtime_pay = 0.0;
    EmployeeClass::overtime_extra = 0.0;
    EmployeeClass::iIndividualSalary = wage * EmployeeClass::hours;

    /* Here you are going to calculate the hours less than 40 hours.
    -   Your base pay is = your hours worked times your wage
    -   Salary = your base pay
    */

    /*
    Implement function call to output the employee information.  Function is 
defined below.
    */

} // End of the else

DisplayEmployInformation();

} //End of Primary Function
void EmployeeClass::DisplayEmployInformation(void) 
{
// This function displays all the employee output information.
//This is your cout statements to display the employee information:
cout << "Employee Name ............. =" << EmployeeName << endl;
cout << "Base Pay .................. =" << basepay << endl;
cout << "Hours in Overtime ......... =" << overtime_hours << endl;
cout << "Overtime Pay Amount........ =" << overtime_pay << endl;
cout << "Total Pay ................. =" << iIndividualSalary << endl;


} // END OF Display Employee Information

double EmployeeClass::Addsomethingup(EmployeeClass Employ1, EmployeeClass 
Employ2, EmployeeClass Employ3)
{
Employ1.DisplayEmployInformation();
// Adds two objects of class Employee passed as 
// function arguments and saves them as the calling object's data member 
values. 
EmployeeClass::iTotal_hours = Employ1.hours + Employ2.hours + Employ3.hours;
double myhours;
EmployeeClass::iTotal_hours = Employ1.hours + Employ2.hours + Employ3.hours;
myhours = Employ1.hours + Employ2.hours + Employ3.hours;
EmployeeClass::iTotal_OvertimeHours = Employ1.overtime_hours + 
Employ2.overtime_hours + Employ3.overtime_hours;
EmployeeClass::iTotal_salaries = Employ1.iIndividualSalary + 
Employ2.iIndividualSalary + Employ3.iIndividualSalary;
/*
Add the total hours for objects 1, 2, and 3.
Add the salaries for each object.
Add the total overtime hours.
*/


// Then display the information below.
cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% " << endl;
cout << "%%%% EMPLOYEE SUMMARY DATA%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% " << endl;
cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% " << endl;
cout << "%%%% Total Employee Salaries ..... = " << iTotal_salaries << endl;
cout << "%%%% Total Employee Hours ........ = " << iTotal_hours << endl;
cout << "%%%% Total Overtime Hours......... = " << iTotal_OvertimeHours << 
endl;
cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% " << endl;
cout << "%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%% " << endl;

return 0;

} // End of function
```

Answer (score 0):

Non-integral static member variables must be defined outside the class definition.

```
class EmployeeClass
{
    // ...

    static double iTotal_salaries;
    static double iIndividualSalary;
    static double iTotal_hours;
    static double iTotal_OvertimeHours;
};

double EmployeeClass::iTotal_salaries = 0.0;
double EmployeeClass::iIndividualSalary = 0.0;
double EmployeeClass::iTotal_hours = 0.0;
double EmployeeClass::iTotal_OvertimeHours = 0.0;
```

Comment: OH MY GOD!!!!!! Thank you so so much! You are my savior!